# How can I use getter with parameter dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I use this getter to make a list:

```
List<CabModel> get cabs() => cabsList.value;
```

and works. But now I need to pass a parameter to filter a list. Something like

```
List<CabModel> get cabs(String value) => cabsList.value;
```

I know, I can't pass parameter in getters, but how do it?

Comment: Just use a normal function and not a getter. (Also, `List<CabModel> get cabs() => ...` uses an empty parameter list and therefore is not valid, but presumably you meant `List<CabModel> get cabs => ...`.)

Comment: @PatrickObafemi Getters can do computation.  For example: `int get foo => someComputation();`.  However, it's usually bad style if they do *expensive* computation since it would belie complexity at the call sites, where they'd look like member variable access.

Comment: @jamesdlin i guess i did not explain myself better. I meant to say in his usecase, he can't filter the list inside a getter because it is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The getter only sends back copy of data, but cannot make any changes/filter stuff. You'd have to create a function that takes in the required parameters and returns the required value.

If you also want to filter and overwrite the existing data, make a setter as well.

```
List FilteredList(...){
  .../required filtering
  return list
}
```

Comment: Getters *can* make changes and filter things.  However, they *shouldn't* make changes or do anything expensive because it'd be unexpected for callers/readers.

Comment: Yes, something to take into consideration as well @JoseO